# How to use Conda kernels while executing jupyter notebook from lambda function

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

How can I execute jupyter notebook using pre-installed conda kernels from lambda function instead of using the default kernel?

Currently, I'm using the following code snippet to execute jupyter notebook from the lambda function.

```
import time
import boto3
import logging
import requests
import websocket

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    sm_client = boto3.client('sagemaker')
    notebook_instance_name = 'Test-Instance'
    url = sm_client.create_presigned_notebook_instance_url \
                (NotebookInstanceName=notebook_instance_name)['AuthorizedUrl']
 
    url_tokens = url.split('/')
    http_proto = url_tokens[0]
    http_hn = url_tokens[2].split('?')[0].split('#')[0]
    
    s = requests.Session()
    r = s.get(url)
    cookies = "; ".join(key + "=" + value for key, value in s.cookies.items())
    
    ws = websocket.create_connection(
        "wss://{}/terminals/websocket/5".format(http_hn),
        cookie=cookies,
        host=http_hn,
        origin=http_proto + "//" + http_hn,
        header = [
            "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36"
        ]
    )
    
    ws.send("""[ "stdin", "jupyter nbconvert --execute --to notebook --inplace /home/ec2-user/SageMaker/test.ipynb --ExecutePreprocessor.kernel_name=python3 --ExecutePreprocessor.timeout=1500\\r" ]""")
```

When I execute jupyter notebook from lambda, it uses the default python kernel available for the Sagemaker instance which has python3.7 installed but if I execute my notebook from sagemaker instance than that uses conda python3.8

Following are the list of available kernels when executing from sagemaker instance:

```
R
Sparkmagic (PySpark)
Sparkmagic (Spark)
Sparkmagic (SparkR)
conda_amazonei_mxnet_p36
conda_amazonei_pytorch_latest_p37
conda_amazonei_tensorflow2_p36
conda_mxnet_p37
conda_python3
conda_pytorch_p38
conda_tensorflow2_p38
```

When I try to execute it from lambda function then only available kernels are:

```
python3
ir
```

This is what I tried:
I created a custom kernel using conda and tried to use that while executing from lambda function, but it didn't work. In fact, if I give anything else other than `python3` in kernel name while executing from lambda function, it doesn't execute the notebook.

Answer (score 0):

See this [github issue](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/515)

tl;dr - activate the conda environment you like to execute on, and then use the jupyter nbconvert command. `jupyter kernelspec list` should show you the available kernels (`kernel_name=python3` should work within the `conda_python3` environment)

Comment: How can I activate a Conda environment on sagemaker from lambda script and then use one of the available kernels?

Comment: `kernel_name=python3` works within the default python kernel available in the sagemaker instance instead of `conda_python3`.

Comment: `jupyter kernelspec list` outputs only two kernels:
`python3` and `ir`  but not `conda_python3` as mentioned in the question

Comment: @MuhammadAzeem - Activate the `conda_python3` environment, and then run in the `python3` kernel.